# Am having problem uploading a profile picture from my react js to my django server using rest api , i use cloudinary to store all my image upload

Tags: reactjs, redux, django-rest-framework, postman, cloudinary

Here is my profile.jsx code that handle the image upload

```
const handleUpload = (event) => {
    console.log(stateUserId,bio,event.target.files[0], 'some click')
    dispatch(actions.uploadProfile(stateUserId,bio,event.target.files[0]))

    // Add code here to upload file to server
    // ...
 }
```

```
<React.Fragment>
      <div className="ProfileStyle">
        <Modal specialId={modalState.useThisId}>
          <div className="bioContent">
            <h3>start editing your bio</h3>
            <form onSubmit={submitBio}>
              <textarea
                ref={bioRef}
                onChange={(event) => {
                  setBio(event.target.value);
                }}
                type="text"
                className="bioInput"
                placeholder="Type in a public bio"
              />
              <div className="deleteContentButtonWrapper">
                <SquareButton
                  type="submit"
                  //  functionHandler={sendBioHandler}
                >
                  Done
                </SquareButton>
                <SquareButton
                  specialStyle={{ background: "red" }}
                  functionHandler={closeModal}
                >
                  Discard Bio
                </SquareButton>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </Modal>
        <div
          className="profileWrapper"
          style={{
            background: `${stateToProps.themeColors.questionBg}`,
            color: `${stateToProps.themeColors.color}`,
          }}
        >
          <div className="ProfilePictureArea">
            <div
              className="profilePic"
              style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${user4})` }}
            >
              <div className="profileCircle2">
              <input
                  type="file"
                  name="file" id="file" accept="image/*"
                  onChange={handleUpload}
                  
                />
                <label htmlFor="file">
                <i className="fas fa-image"></i>
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="profileCircle1"></div>
          </div>

          <div className="bioArea">
            <h1
              className="profileName"
              style={{
                background: `${stateToProps.themeColors.questionBg}`,
                color: `${stateToProps.themeColors.color}`,
              }}
            >
              THE USER NAMES
            </h1>
            <div className="bioDesc">
              <div
                className="bio"
                style={{
                  background: `${stateToProps.themeColors.questionBg}`,
                  color: `${stateToProps.themeColors.color}`,
                }}
              >
                bio
              </div>
              <p>{bio}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="bioEdit" onClick={openModal}>
              <i className="fas fa-plus"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <h5
          className="yourRecentPost"
          style={{
            color: `${stateToProps.themeColors.color}`,
          }}
        >
          Your recent Questions
        </h5>

        {children}
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
```

Here is my redux axios action that handle my request

```
export const uploadProfile = (profileId,profileData,profileImage) => {
    // console.log(profileData,profileImage)
    let post = {
        profileData:profileData,
        image:profileImage,
    }
    console.log(post)
    return dispatch => {
        axios.put(`https://querybackendapi.herokuapp.com/api/profiles/${profileId}/`, post)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        })
        .then(err => console.log(err))
    }
}
```

Here is my django profile.models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = CloudinaryField('image')
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

NOTE: if i use postman or django admin to select an image from my desktop am able to successfully upload a profile pic but when i use react js(rest api)

[image]

even if it get upload, cloudinary is not able to decode the format so no image is displayed i realy dont know where the problem is coming from

Answer (score 0):

I work as a Developer Support Engineer over at Cloudinary. I've taken a look at our logs and can see a number of successful uploads from you - presumably these are your Django admin and/or Postman uploads.

I did see one upload with a 400 response, and upon investigation it turns out this was due to an invalid signature. The request came through at 2021-07-23T18:12 (UTC), however the signature was signed as 2021-07-23 07:21:02. As signatures are only valid for an hour, this may be the cause of your issues uploading.

Could I please ask you to check this, and also provide the full json response and/or console output from when you try to upload via React?

I see you've opened a ticket via our support center (ref 156824) so if you'd prefer to reply there in case of any identifying information, you're welcome to do so.

Looking forward to hearing back from you.

Thanks,
-Danny